# Выполнение функции несколько раз

Tags: база-данных, php

Вывожу через row записи из бд.
Для каждой записи должна выполниться одна функция, но результаты должны занестись в разные переменные. Смотрим.

```
$bid = $row["bid"]; // id записи, далее сама функция
function strcode($str, $passw="")
{
$salt = "54321";
$len = strlen($str);
$gamma = '';
$n = $len>100 ? 8 : 2;
while( strlen($gamma)<$len )
{
  $gamma .= substr(pack('H*', sha1($passw.$gamma.$salt)), 0, $n);
}
 return $str^$gamma;
}

${'prehash_'.$bid} = "$itemid-$id"; //Две динамические переменные
${'hash_'.$bid} = base64_encode(strcode(${'prehash_'.$bid}, '12345'));

echo '<a href="../download/'.${'hash_'.$bid}.'">Скачать</a>'; } ?>
```

По идее, всё верно, но выводит только одну запись, и на этом конец. Вроде, переменные сделал динамические, повторений нет, но не работает. Может, потому что обращение идёт постоянно к одной функции? Хотя, думаю, не в этом дело. **Помогите**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вижу цикла) Судя по коду, один раз и будет)

Comment: Этот код в цикле само собой, здесь не написал просто.

Comment: Ну а может, цикл один раз выполняется?

Comment: Нет. С циклом всё нормально.

Comment: Все равно отредактируйте с циклом, чтобы видели весь цикл.